# Tela de registro return

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma tela de registro, que compara o texto do edittext com o campo do banco, e essa comparação está funcionando normalmente.

O que eu gostaria de fazer, é que se já houvesse o campo do e-mail no banco, a atividade não prossiga.

Código:

```
 mEmail = email.getText().toString();

        new getUser().execute();




        btnfincad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (("".equals(email.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Nenhum campo pode ser nulo !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (("".equals(password.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Nenhum campo pode ser nulo !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (("".equals(nick.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Nenhum campo pode ser nulo !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (("".equals(number.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Nenhum campo pode ser nulo !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (("".equals(sexo.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Nenhum campo pode ser nulo !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (("".equals(data.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Nenhum campo pode ser nulo !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (("".equals(number.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Nenhum campo pode ser nulo !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }






                mName = name.getText().toString();
                mNick = nick.getText().toString();
                mPassword = password.getText().toString();
                mNumber = number.getText().toString();
                mSexo = sexo.getText().toString();
                mData = data.getText().toString();
                mEmail = email.getText().toString();
```

Meu `return` que não funciona corretamente é este:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

           super.onPostExecute(result);


           try {

               JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

               JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json.getString("resource"));
               for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                   JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                   String email = jsonObj.getString("tx_email");
                   System.out.println(email);


                   if (mEmail.equals(email)) {
                       Toast.makeText(PostCadastro.this, "Email já existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return ;


                   }
               }


           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
```

Comment: Como assim não funciona? Não é chamado ou não sai do método? Talvez o que você precise seja o `break;` ao invés do `return;`

Comment: Mesmo com o break não funciona,eu queria que ele não deixasse ir pra proxima activity se o email ja existisse entende ?

Comment: Tu tens uma chamada assíncrona não tem como fazer com que a Thread principal fique esperando essa chamada. Terás que tratar no retorno dessa chamada. Se o email é invalido não vai para próxima tela.

Comment: Robson como posso resolver isso ?Sou estagiario em Android